# Calculating remainder of $666^{666}$ when divided by $1000$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, congruences

I want to calculate the remainder of $666^{666}$ when divided by $1000$. But for the usual methods I use the divisor is very big. Furthermore $1000$ is not a prime, $666$ is a zero divisor in $\mathbb{Z}_{1000}$.

I have some thought about it, here it is...

1. There does not exist $n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $666^n\equiv 1\,\pmod{\!1000}$
2. $666$ may be nilpotent with degree $n \leq 666$. In this case $666^{666}\equiv 0\,\pmod{\!1000}$.
3. $666$ may be nilpotent with degree $n \geq 666$. If I don't know the exact degree I don't know what to do here.
4. $666$ might be non-nilpotent. For example $4\in\mathbb{Z}_6$ is idempotent. But $666$ is not idempotent, as $666^2\equiv 556\,\pmod{\!1000}$, so even if $666$ is not nilpotent I don't see the answer so easily. If $666$ is not nilpotent, and as it is not idempotent, I don't know what to do here.

Any idea?

Comment: Try calculating $666^{666} \pmod{8}$ and $666^{666} \pmod{125}$. Then use the Chinese Remainder Theorem. This will be a bit easier than calculating $666^{666}\pmod{1000}$ directly.

Comment: @JimmyK4542's comment is excellent, especially since the first calculation is obviously zero. The second exponentiation is not difficult if you use [exponentiation by squaring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring) (also called binary exponentiation).

Comment: It seems really useful. I'll try.

Comment: $666$ cannot possibly be nilpotent in $\Bbb Z_{1000}$, since $1000=2^3\cdot 5^3$; here $2$ is a factor of $666$, but $5$ isn't. $a$ is nilpotent in $\Bbb Z_{n}$ iff $(p\mid n\,\Rightarrow\, p\mid a)$.

Comment: That's a nice proposition.
Now that I remember, I knew that proposition, but had never used it so I forgot it...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

$666^{666}$ is certainly a multiple of $8$, and Euler's theorem tells us that
$$666^{666}\equiv41^{66}\pmod{125}$$
Now, we can do, for example:
$$41^{66}\equiv56^{33}\equiv56\cdot11^{16}\equiv56\cdot4^8\equiv56\cdot6^2\equiv16\pmod{125}$$

Thus, since $16$ is a multiple of $8$,

$$666^{666}\equiv 16\pmod{1000}$$

Comment: Calculations have been made by hand. There could be mistakes, but I hope that the strategy is clear.

Comment: $666\equiv 41\not\equiv -9\,\pmod{\! 125}$.

Comment: Edited: I hope that there are no mistakes now, but...

Comment: I solved it in a way similar to this (A little longer fiinding the remainder when divided by 125), thanks.

Comment: You don't need any calculations at all. See my answer.

Answer (score 2):

As $3\cdot666=2000-2\equiv-2\pmod{1000}$

$(3\cdot666)^{666}\equiv(-2)^{666}\pmod{1000}$

As $(3,1000)=1,666^{666}\equiv(3^{-1})^{666}2^{666}\pmod{1000}$

Let us  find $\displaystyle3^{-666}\cdot2^{666-3}\pmod{\dfrac{1000}8}$

As $\displaystyle\phi(125)=100,-666\equiv34,663\equiv63\pmod{100}$

$\displaystyle3^{-666}\cdot2^{663}\equiv3^{34}2^{63}\pmod{125}$

Now $\displaystyle3^5\equiv-7\pmod{125},$
$\displaystyle3^{34}=3^4(3^5)^6\equiv3^4(-7)^6\equiv(80+1)(50-1)^3\equiv3\cdot50-80-1\pmod{125}\equiv69$

$2^7\equiv3\pmod{125}\implies2^{63}=(2^7)^9\equiv3^9\pmod{125}$

$3^9=3^{-1}(3^5)^2\equiv3^{-1}(-7)^2\equiv42\cdot49\equiv(50-8)(50-1)\equiv8-9\cdot50\equiv-67$

$\implies3^{34}2^{63}\equiv69(-67)\equiv(70-1)(-70+3)\equiv2\pmod{125}$

$\implies3^{-666}2^{666}\equiv2^3\cdot2\pmod{2^3\cdot125}$

Comment: No, $666\equiv 41\,\pmod{\! 125}$.

Comment: @user26486, Please find the rectified version

Answer (score 2):

Here's a relatively naïve approach. Start listing powers of $666$
modulo $1000$:

$$\begin{eqnarray}
666^2    &\equiv&  556 \pmod{1000}, \\
666^3    &\equiv&  296 \pmod{1000}, \\
666^4    &\equiv&  136 \pmod{1000}, \\
666^5    &\equiv&  576 \pmod{1000}, \\
666^6    &\equiv&  616 \pmod{1000}, \\
666^7    &\equiv&  256 \pmod{1000}, \\
666^8    &\equiv&  496 \pmod{1000}, \\
666^9    &\equiv&  336 \pmod{1000}, \\
666^{10} &\equiv&  776 \pmod{1000}, \\
666^{11} &\equiv&  816 \pmod{1000}, \\
666^{12} &\equiv&  456 \pmod{1000}.
\end{eqnarray}$$

A pattern is starting to emerge:
$$\begin{eqnarray}
666^8    &\equiv&  666^3 + 200 \pmod{1000}, \\
666^9    &\equiv&  666^4 + 200 \pmod{1000}, \\
666^{10} &\equiv&  666^5 + 200 \pmod{1000}, \\
666^{11} &\equiv&  666^6 + 200 \pmod{1000}, \\
666^{12} &\equiv&  666^7 + 200 \pmod{1000}.
\end{eqnarray}$$

Will this pattern continue?
Observe that $666 \cdot 200 \equiv 200 \pmod{1000},$
so $666^5 \cdot 200 \equiv 200 \pmod{1000},$
and so if 
$$666^n \equiv  666^{n-5} + 200 \pmod{1000}$$
then 
$$\begin{eqnarray}
666^{n+5} &\equiv& 666^5 (666^{n-5} + 200) \pmod{1000} \\
          &\equiv& 666^n + 200 \pmod{1000}.
\end{eqnarray}$$
The identity $666^{n+5} \equiv  666^n + 200 \pmod{1000}$ 
therefore holds for any $n \geq 3$.

Repeat this five times and we find that for $n\geq 3,$
$$666^{n+25} \equiv 666^n \pmod{1000}.$$

Since $666 \equiv 16 \pmod{25},$
it follows that
$$\begin{eqnarray}
666^{666} &\equiv& 666^{16} \pmod{1000} \\
          &\equiv& 666^{11} + 200 \pmod{1000} \\
          &\equiv& 666^{6}  + 400 \pmod{1000} \\
          &\equiv& 16 \pmod{1000}.
\end{eqnarray}$$

Answer (score 2):

$$666^{666}=(670-4)^{666}=(4-670)^{666}$$

$$(4-670)^{666}\equiv4^{666}-\binom{666}14^{665}\cdot670^1+\binom{666}24^{664}\cdot670^2\pmod{1000}$$

Now $\displaystyle\binom{666}2\equiv0\pmod5$
$\displaystyle\implies4^{664}\binom{666}2\equiv0\pmod{10}$

$\displaystyle\implies4^{664}\binom{666}2\cdot670^2\equiv0\pmod{1000}$

So, we need $S\equiv\displaystyle4^{666}-\binom{666}14^{665}\cdot670^1\pmod{1000}$

Now $\displaystyle\binom{666}1\cdot67=(670-4)(70-3)\equiv-280-210+12\equiv22\pmod{100}$

$\displaystyle\implies\binom{666}14^{665}\cdot670^1\equiv220\pmod{1000}$

$S\equiv4^{666}-4^{665}\cdot220\equiv-4^{665}(220-4)\equiv-27\cdot2^{3+2\cdot665}\pmod{1000}$

Now $\displaystyle\phi(125)=100,2\cdot665\equiv30\pmod{100}\implies2^{2\cdot665}\equiv2^{30}\pmod{125}$

and $\displaystyle2^7\equiv3\pmod{125},2^{30}=2^2(2^7)^4\equiv4\cdot3^4\equiv74\pmod{125}$

$\displaystyle\implies -27\cdot2^{2\cdot665}\equiv-27\cdot74\pmod{125}\equiv-(25+2)(75-1)\equiv2\pmod{125}$

$\displaystyle\implies-27\cdot2^{3+2\cdot665}\equiv2\cdot2^3\pmod{125\cdot2^3}$

Answer (score 2):

**Brute Force Approach**

We can use the [Square and Multiply Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring).

Noting that $666=1010011010_\text{two}$, we will write the exponents in base two:
$$
\begin{align}
666^0&\equiv\hphantom{00}1\pmod{1000}\\
666^1&\equiv666\pmod{1000}&\text{multiply by }666\\
666^{10}&\equiv556\pmod{1000}&\text{square}\\
666^{100}&\equiv136\pmod{1000}&\text{square}\\
666^{101}&\equiv576\pmod{1000}&\text{multiply by }666\\
666^{1010}&\equiv776\pmod{1000}&\text{square}\\
666^{10100}&\equiv176\pmod{1000}&\text{square}\\
666^{101000}&\equiv976\pmod{1000}&\text{square}\\
666^{101001}&\equiv\hphantom{0}16\pmod{1000}&\text{multiply by }666\\
666^{1010010}&\equiv256\pmod{1000}&\text{square}\\
666^{1010011}&\equiv496\pmod{1000}&\text{multiply by }666\\
666^{10100110}&\equiv\hphantom{0}16\pmod{1000}&\text{square}\\
666^{101001100}&\equiv256\pmod{1000}&\text{square}\\
666^{101001101}&\equiv496\pmod{1000}&\text{multiply by }666\\
666^{1010011010}&\equiv\hphantom{0}16\pmod{1000}&\text{square}\\
\end{align}
$$

---

**A Bit More Intelligent Approach**

We can reduce the problem by breaking down the modulus into prime factors:
$$
666^{666}\equiv0\pmod{8}
$$
Since $\phi(125)=100$,
$$
666^{666}\equiv41^{66}\pmod{125}
$$
We can still use the Square and Multiply Algorithm in this situation. Since $66=1000010_\text{two}$
$$
\begin{align}
41^0&\equiv\hphantom{00}1\pmod{125}\\
41^1&\equiv\hphantom{0}41\pmod{125}&\text{multiply by }41\\
41^{10}&\equiv\hphantom{0}56\pmod{125}&\text{square}\\
41^{100}&\equiv\hphantom{0}11\pmod{125}&\text{square}\\
41^{1000}&\equiv\hphantom{}121\pmod{125}&\text{square}\\
41^{10000}&\equiv\hphantom{0}16\pmod{125}&\text{square}\\
41^{100000}&\equiv\hphantom{00}6\pmod{125}&\text{square}\\
41^{100001}&\equiv\hphantom{}121\pmod{125}&\text{multiply by }41\\
41^{1000010}&\equiv\hphantom{0}16\pmod{125}&\text{square}
\end{align}
$$
Thus,
$$
666^{666}\equiv0\pmod{8}\qquad\text{and}\qquad666^{666}\equiv16\pmod{125}
$$
Since $16\equiv0\pmod{8}$, the solution to the Chinese Remainder Problem is immediately evident. That is,
$$
666^{666}\equiv16\pmod{1000}
$$

Answer (score 2):

$\varphi(125)=100$, so by [Euler's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler's_theorem) and [Binomial theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem):

$$666^{666}\equiv 41^{666\pmod{\! 100}}\equiv (1+40)^{66}\pmod{\! 125}$$

$$\equiv 1+\binom{66}{1}40+\underbrace{\binom{66}{2}}_{\text{divisible by }5}40^2\equiv 1+(75-9)40\pmod{\! 125}$$

$$\equiv 1+(1-10)(50-10)\equiv 1+50-10+100\equiv 16\pmod{\! 125}$$

Since $(125,8)=1$:

$$125,8\mid 666^{666}-16\iff 1000\mid 666^{666}-16$$